# Python3, json causes TypeError but simplejson doesn't

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm running the latest Python3 (with the Anaconda distribution) and have a problem with the standard library installed json which causes the Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Think\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "C:\Users\Think\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 181, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\Think\my_server.py", line 148, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\Think\my_server.py", line 144, in wsgi_app
        response = self.dispatch_request(request)
      File "C:\Users\Think\my_server.py", line 80, in dispatch_request
        return getattr(self, 'on_' + endpoint)(request, **values)
      File "C:\Users\Think\my_server.py", line 54, in on_xapi_request
        json_data = self.load_json(request.data)
      File "C:\Users\Think\my_server.py", line 60, in load_json
        return json.loads(data)
      File "C:\Users\Think\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
        s.__class__.__name__))

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

But, simplejson doesn't cause the error.

Comment: You are only making statement. This is a Q&A site, it helps to put an interrogative sentence in your posts, so we don't have to guess what the question might be.

Comment: + you should give us some code, not only traceback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.decode('utf-8')` before passing to `json.loads`

I think this line:

```
return json.loads(data)
```

is causing the problem. Decode data before passing it to this function.

Comment: Just using `return json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))` works too and is more concise.

Comment: That did it. Many thanks. It is weird that simplejson worked and json didn't. I'm guessing it's because python3 is strict about str and bytes but simplejson isn't.